Using batch to check if files exist, store filenames into an array and move them
I have three or more directories with subdirectories in which I have to check and sort thousands of files named "00001_*.jpg" to "99999_*.jpg".
But for the sake of keeping it simple, we will test a sample of 20 images.
For example I have three parent directories A, B and C. Inside of directory B are four images 00017_0.jpg, 00018_0.jpg, 00019_0.jpg and 00020_0.jpg. I would like to run a script which detects those filenames e.g. in directory A and move them into a subdirectory named Check, (A\Check).
I have tried to store filenames into an array, but I am already stuck. I tried to store them into list_1, but when I echo the result I get nothing "".
I edit the path to the images in directory B in FolderPath using parameters: default, default, 20
Resulting in:
Start value (default: 1):
Increment by: (default: 1):
Last value (default: 99999): 20
Not exist: 00001_0.jpg
Not exist: 00002_0.jpg
Not exist: 00003_0.jpg
Not exist: 00004_0.jpg
Not exist: 00005_0.jpg
Not exist: 00006_0.jpg
Not exist: 00007_0.jpg
Not exist: 00008_0.jpg
Not exist: 00009_0.jpg
Not exist: 00010_0.jpg
Not exist: 00011_0.jpg
Not exist: 00012_0.jpg
Not exist: 00013_0.jpg
Not exist: 00014_0.jpg
Not exist: 00015_0.jpg
Not exist: 00016_0.jpg
Found file: 00017_0.jpg
Found file: 00018_0.jpg
Found file: 00019_0.jpg
Found file: 00020_0.jpg
"The length of the array is" 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Below is my adaption of this script.
It found the files in directory B, but my additions regarding list_1 array have not worked out, so I am unable to move them the Check subdirectory; (this part is not yet scripted).
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "list_1="
set "ValueStart=1"
set "ValueIncrement=1"
set "ValueLast=99999"
set /P "ValueStart=Start value (default: %ValueStart%): " 
set /P "ValueIncrement=Increment by: (default: %ValueIncrement%): "
set /P "ValueLast=Last value (default: %ValueLast%): "

set "FolderPath=%USERPROFILE%\folder\subfolder"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%G in (%ValueStart%,%ValueIncrement%,%ValueLast%) do (
    if %%G LSS 100000 (
        set "FileName=0000%%G"
        set "FileName=!FileName:~-5!_0.jpg"
    ) else set "FileName=%%G_0.jpg"
    if exist "!FolderPath!\!FileName!" (
        set "list_1[%%G]=FileName"
        echo Found file: !FileName!) else echo Not exist: !FileName!
)

set "x=0"
:SymLoop 

if defined list_1[%x%] ( 
   call echo %%list_1[%x%]%% 
   set /a "x+=1"
   GOTO :SymLoop 
)
echo "The length of the array is" %x%
pause
endlocal


How many arrays have you ever seen whereby the items are separated with the + character. Or more to the point, when have you ever seen the + character being accepted as a For loop separator? The + character has no special meaning in a batch file, it is not used to join strings. Also why are you using the string FileName, rather than the variable named FileName.

@Compo I don't know how batch works. Its clumsy but I attempted to add filenames into one long string called list_1 which needs to be made into an array. I don't know how to build an array in batch which will list the filenames. Right now I can't even get the long string to print or echo?

There is a search facility at the top oi each page of this site, and help on how to filter the search terms, please use it to learn how to achieve your goal. We are not here to link those existing examples for you, and we are not here to write code for you to your set of requirements. Batch files do not have arrays, so what you will need is a string of substrings to separate and run through in a loop of some sort. You can start by possibly changing set list_1=list_1+"FileName" to set "list_1=!list_1! "!FileName!"", and moving the position of endlocal.

Also set list_1="", should read as Set "list_1=", to undefine the variable at the outset, using the syntax already given in the code you were given previously.

@Compo I ditched the long string idea and tried to create an array. The original script has been updated. I got nothing echoed meaning my syntax is wrong or my code is

set "x = 0" defines a variable named x<space> with a value of <space>0. I'm sure that wasn't the intention, and cannot understand why you've not maintained the set syntax used everywhere else in your code. Please concentrate on what you are doing, you should be able to identify these things before bothering other people with them.

@Compo if I fix to set "x=0" I get "The length of the array is" 0. No array was created

Are you aware that endlocal destroys any variables since the last setlocal?

@Stephan I could remove endlocal before set "x=0" but I do not think I am creating an array? I didn't think if an array was created that it would destroy an array? If I remove and only have endlocal at the end of the script I still get a result of 0 and no array.

Well, you don't have a file named 000000_0.jpg, do you? The first iteration of your last loop checks if defined list_1[0], which it is not. Put the set /a x+=1 before the if exist line (this also leaves x at the last correct value). I didn't check, if you actually created  an array, but you definitively don't echo it (a simpler method is just set list1[, which shows all variables starting with list1[ (The concept of an array doesn't exist in cmd, it is actually just a bunch of independent variables)

@Compo has already told you that Batch files do not have arrays, so you can stop trying to create an array. There is no concept of an array in Windows batch.

Also, I don't understand the hoops you're trying to jump through. If you have files in each directory, you don't need a list or an array or anything else. cd A & move *.jpg Check\ is all you need. If you have more than four, use a wildcard that matches. You could write a loop to go through A, B and C to perform the same thing, or just write a three-line batch file. If you have to check for the existence of each file, then use if exists 000017.jpg move 000017.jpg Check\.

@Ken White, is set "list_1[%%G]=FileName" in the earlier loop wrong SymLoop should list them all as independent variables. Like an array (but a list of variables eg list_1[0] and onwards)?

Yes. Once again, there is no concept of an array in Windows batch. Maybe, now that this is the third time that's explained to you, it will get through. I don't understand why you're taking what should be a simple task and making it so very complicated.

Ok I have managed to do it. Will post the code later after I have cleaned it up. It is only my second ever batch script. Going to bed. I would appreciate it if whomever down voted my question to kindly remove it.

@Modboy, whilst the downvoter may well do that after you have provided an answer, (the downvote button is generally for lack of shown effort), there's a good chance they will not visit this question again. Additionally asking for downvote reasons, and for them to be withdrawn is actually frowned upon on this site.

It will save me years of time. I don't need an array to move files but arrays were important to me as they offered a structure I am able to scale. Moves and many other tasks can now be automated from arrays. Expanding the script below can move the images that need to be checked. Which is one of many manually laborious Windows tasks that I never have to do again :) ...
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "List_1="
set "ValueStart=0"
set "ValueIncrement=1"
set "ValueLast=99999"
set /P "ValueStart=Start value (default: %ValueStart%): " 
set /P "ValueIncrement=Increment by: (default: %ValueIncrement%): "
set /P "ValueLast=Last value (default: %ValueLast%): "

set "FolderPath=%USERPROFILE%\folder\subfolder"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%G in (%ValueStart%,%ValueIncrement%,%ValueLast%) do (
    if %%G LSS 100000 (
        set "FileName=0000%%G"
        set "FileName=!FileName:~-5!_0.jpg"
    ) else set "FileName=%%G_0.jpg"
    if exist "!FolderPath!\!FileName!" (
        set "List_1[%%G]=!FileName!"
        set List_1[%%G]=!list_1[%%G]!
        echo Found file: !FileName!
    ) else  (
            set List_1[%%G]=""
            echo Not exist: !FileName!
            )
    echo List_1[%%G]=!List_1[%%G]!
)

pause
endlocal

Results in
Start value (default: 0):
Increment by: (default: 1):
Last value (default: 99999): 20
Not exist: 00000_0.jpg
List_1[0]=""
Not exist: 00001_0.jpg
List_1[1]=""
Not exist: 00002_0.jpg
List_1[2]=""
Not exist: 00003_0.jpg
List_1[3]=""
Not exist: 00004_0.jpg
List_1[4]=""
Not exist: 00005_0.jpg
List_1[5]=""
Not exist: 00006_0.jpg
List_1[6]=""
Not exist: 00007_0.jpg
List_1[7]=""
Not exist: 00008_0.jpg
List_1[8]=""
Not exist: 00009_0.jpg
List_1[9]=""
Not exist: 00010_0.jpg
List_1[10]=""
Not exist: 00011_0.jpg
List_1[11]=""
Not exist: 00012_0.jpg
List_1[12]=""
Not exist: 00013_0.jpg
List_1[13]=""
Not exist: 00014_0.jpg
List_1[14]=""
Not exist: 00015_0.jpg
List_1[15]=""
Not exist: 00016_0.jpg
List_1[16]=""
Found file: 00017_0.jpg
List_1[17]=00017_0.jpg
Found file: 00018_0.jpg
List_1[18]=00018_0.jpg
Found file: 00019_0.jpg
List_1[19]=00019_0.jpg
Found file: 00020_0.jpg
List_1[20]=00020_0.jpg
Press any key to continue . . .

